# Map chart not working in Oracle APEX 5.1.4

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I am receiving following message when i use Map chart in Oracle APEX 5.1.4

apex feature is not supported plot type map

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer . It Flash Issue

Following is the work around
 ANYCHART FLASH-BASED CHARTS NOT RENDERING USING CHROME 60+
If you use Chrome 60 or later, you may notice that AnyChart Flash-based map charts and Gantt charts may no longer render in the browser, and Flash-based charts are rendering as HTML5 instead of Flash. This is due to a change in the settings for the browser.
Workaround: In Chrome, edit the browser Flash settings via chrome://settings/content/flash?search=flash, and add the instance URL for the site using the Flash-based content to the 'Allow' list for Flash.